# Is it safe to stop phpMyAdmin while it's modifying an attribute?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a column in a table where I wanted to change the attribute to UNSIGNED ZEROFILL using phpMyAdmin. I THOUGHT it would be quick as there were only about 25k records that needed it, but so far it's taken about 2 hours. The browser page is still "Loading", but the HD light is going mad so it IS doing something.

The problem is I have NOOOO idea how long it will take. If it takes more than 24hrs I will probably have to give up and shut down but is that safe to do? If I were to stop the MySQL server, would it damage the table? I imagine the answer is going to be "yes".

```
OS = Win 7
Server = XAMPP
DB = InnoDB
```

In the table files folder I can see it's creating what appears to be a temporary file.

Currently, the "temp" (if that's what it is) .idb file is 610MB. The original idb is 6GB. Is it actually creating a new idb file? Could I maybe take it that it's 10% done?

Comment: It should go without saying, but if you're afraid of data loss, you should have a backup you can restore from, just in case. Sorry, I can't say anything about the question, though. My guess would be that phpMyAdmin, being just a front-end to mysql, should be ok to close, with the sql query continuing in background on the mysql server.